# TYPO3 scheduler task executed via cli does not clear page cache when using custom caching backend

Tags: php, caching, typo3, command-line-interface

I'm Using TYPO3 9.5.14 and I'm importing News from an external database. After the import I want to clear the cache of the page where the news are rendered.

I'm using an apcu caching backend, so not the standard database caching backend of TYPO3. I created a scheduler task for the news import, and here is the problem:

When I call the scheduler task via the backend module then everything is fine. The news are imported and the page cache is cleared. But when a cronjob calls the scheduler task via cli, the news are imported but the page cache doens't get cleared. What am I missing?

Here's the scheduler task class:

```
class NewsUpdateTask extends \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask
{   
    public function execute()
    {   
        //some code that does the import...

        $cacheManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager::class);
        $cacheManager->flushCachesInGroupByTags('pages', ['pageId_2']);

        return true;
    }      
}
```

The apcu caching backend configuration is included in the AdditionalConfiguration.php like this:

```
include_once "MwCachingConfiguration.php";
```

and looks like this:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('mw_setCacheBackend')) {
    function mw_setCacheBackend($backendClassName, $cacheName, $lifetime = NULL)
    {
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$cacheName]['backend'] = $backendClassName;
        if (isset($lifetime))
        {
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$cacheName]['options'] = array("defaultLifetime" => $lifetime);
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$cacheName]['options'] = array();
        }
    }
}

$mw_apcExtensionLoaded = extension_loaded('apc');
$mw_apcuExtensionLoaded = extension_loaded('apcu');
$mw_apcAvailable = $mw_apcExtensionLoaded || $mw_apcuExtensionLoaded;
$mw_apcEnabled = ini_get('apc.enabled') == TRUE;

if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' && TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext() !== 'Development' && $mw_apcAvailable && $mw_apcEnabled) {
    $mw_backendClassName = $mw_apcExtensionLoaded ? 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\ApcBackend'
        : 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\ApcuBackend';
} else {
    $mw_backendClassName = 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\FileBackend';
}

$version = TYPO3_version;

if (substr($version,0,2) === "10")
{
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'hash');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'pages');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'pagesection', 2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'rootline',2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'imagesizes', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase', 0);
} elseif ($version[0] === "9") {
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_hash');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pages');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pagesection', 2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_rootline',2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_imagesizes', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_reflection', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_datamapfactory_datamap', 0);
} elseif ($version[0] === "8" || $version[0] === "6") {
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_hash');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pages');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_datamapfactory_datamap');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pagesection', 2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_rootline',2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_imagesizes', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_object', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_reflection', 0);
} elseif ($version[0] === "7") {
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_hash');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pages');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_datamapfactory_datamap');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_typo3dbbackend_queries');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pagesection', 2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_rootline',2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_imagesizes', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_object', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_reflection', 0);
} else {
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_hash');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pages');
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_pagesection', 2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_rootline',2592000);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'cache_imagesizes', 0);
    mw_setCacheBackend($mw_backendClassName, 'extbase_datamapfactory_datamap', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your code:

```
if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' && TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext() !== 'Development' && $mw_apcAvailable && $mw_apcEnabled) {
    $mw_backendClassName = $mw_apcExtensionLoaded ? 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\ApcBackend'
    : 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\ApcuBackend';
} else {
    $mw_backendClassName = 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\FileBackend';
}
```

APCu is only used for **PHP_SAPI !== 'cli'**, so there is no such cache when you execute your code via cronjob/cli. The cronjob will only clear this cache with its FileBackend.

Comment: I tried removing PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' from the if statement, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that apc(u) is sapi/context depending. You cannot access/work with the apc(c) cache from another context.

That is how apc(u) works.

That means, that you cannot set valu in a sapi context(fpm,cli,cgi,) and access it from another. They have no connection in between.

So, even if you enable apc(u) through php.ini settings in cli also (which is per default disabled), and configurer the Typo3 Backend Adapter for APCU also, it generally will work -- as seperated data container silos.

Further more, each invokation of an cli script / process will start with an empty, new acpu data silo.

This is a restriction from apc(u), not Typo3. And nothing, the adapter or typo3 can overcome or change in behavoior.

If you using CLI and WebRequest, using cache which are shared (file,database,redis,memcache), everything will be alright.

This makes APCU mainly useless, if you want to delete/rebuild caches from commandline which are used in another, non cli context.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. The shared hosting of the project only offers apcu caching, no redis/memcache :(

Comment: If you have the use case to use/clear caches from cmd line and web context - yes. If not, it can be useful.

We have several projects hosted on the same provider (the code snippet tells us which provider).

We have a big project, whih needs 15gb only for the cache_page. On the 32bit structure from that hoster, you cannot use apcu for more than 2GB (apcu and opcode combined) per account.

We have tested with apcu and a 30GB cache configuration - an have large issues. apcu is throing away page cache items, even if the cache is only used ~50%. 
Seems like some thing with fragmentation.